# How to test invalid session after 30 days?

Tags: android, testing

I need to test login session on android app that need to stay 30 days before automatically logout.

How to skip this 30 days virtually on Android environment?

The other way is ask developer to shorten the session to 1 hour to test and change that to 30 days right before release

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have some session key(AUTH_TOKEN) as well as session expiry time(TOKEN_EXPIRY) in your session. You store your session credentials in shared pref. Now you can validity of your session like this.

```
public static boolean isSessionValid() {
        String authToken = SharedPref.getStringValue("AUTH_TOKEN");
        if (AppUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) return false;
        long expiryTimeMillis = SharedPref.getLongValue("TOKEN_EXPIRY");
        return (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() < expiryTimeMillis);
    }
```

Call this function to check session validity wherever app requires.